# What is this install.sh doing?

Tags: linux, makefile

I am not sure what is the if function testing and what is OPT=opt. I am trying to compile some code that was not written by me. I think this is calling a makefile.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ 'x'${1} == 'xclean' ]
then
  make OPT=opt clean
else
  make OPT=opt
fi
```

When I run this I get

> ./install.sh: 2: ./install.sh: x: not found

Comment: If first parameter is 'clean' then call `make OPT=opt clean` otherwise call `make OPT=opt`

Comment: x is a variable? what does it mean xclean?

Comment: It means... if I append the value of the first parameter to the letter `x`, does it then make the word `xclean`. So, it essentially tests if the script was called with the parameter `clean`. People do it to avoid problems if there is no parameter supplied when the parameter would evaluate to nothing, then you would be comparing nothing with something and get a problem.

Comment: @MarkSetchell strange, because I am not sure what the first parameter is, since it's not stated anywhere in the shell script.

Comment: It means the parameter on the command line when the script is started, so if you type `./install.sh clean` it will then run `make OPT=opt clean`. If you start the script by typing simply `./install.sh`, it will just run `make opt=OPT`. The `make` then invokes your `Makefile` with the parameters as described above.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks that makes perfect sense. Put this in the answer so I can give you some kudos :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, it tests if the script was called with the parameter `clean`. People do it to avoid problems if there is no parameter supplied when the parameter would evaluate to nothing, then you would be comparing nothing with something and get a problem.

It means the parameter on the command line when the script is started, so if you type

```
./install.sh clean
```

it will then run `make OPT=opt clean`.

If you start the script by typing simply

```
./install.sh
```

it will just run `make opt=OPT`. The `make` then invokes your Makefile with the parameters as described above.